# Mongoose Aggregation multiple dynamic fields in $match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question with how to mongoose aggregation multiple $match?

For example i have a route ->

```
api/job/filter/$id_job_position/$job_status/$id_city
$id_job_position is ObjectId
$job_status is Full Time, Part Time or Freelance
$id_city is ObjectId
```

My aggregation code:

```
    db.job.aggregate([
      { $match: { 
        job_position: ObjectId(id_job_position),
        city: ObjectId(id_city),
        job_status: job_status,
        show: true,
      }},
    ])
```

but when user only fill for $id_job_position and then its return error because $job_status is no data, and error "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters" because its ObjectId.

I want it flexible, for example if user only fill $job_status, then my aggregation is only run job_status select data.

And the code will become like this:

`db.job.aggregate([{ $match: { job_status: job_status, show: true }} ])`

I have no idea how to make it. Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply create a query object and fill required attributes based on your requirement

```
const userInput = {};
const query = {};
    
if (userInput.job_position) query.job_position = userInput.job_position    
if (userInput.job_status) query.job_status = userInput.job_status
    
db.job.aggregate([{ $match: query}])
```